# How to I give my mesh object (STL/OBJ) a flat surface?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, stl, cad, obj

When scanning objects like sculptures using Kiri Engine (photogrammetry) often the bottom is open. What I currently do after exporting to OBJ, is opening it in my RevoScan app and use the "fill holes" feature to select it and fill it. However that's usually not entirely flat and suitable for printing and results in artifacts. What I then do it simply lower the object when slicing to sub-zero/a negative value to have a small part of the object be under the bed, basically cutting it off and leaving a perfectly flat surface in my gcode.

However, I want to really be able to do this in my STL/OBJ file already for publishing to Thingiverse. How do I alter the STL/OBJ file to basically achieve the same, but in my object rather than in the final gcode?

Comment: Please use the search function, I remember this has been asked before.

Comment: I did. Please mark as duplicate and link to the original because I couldn't find it.

Comment: Do you have any experience with 3D editing software or 3D printing slicer software?

Comment: Apparently not enough. I do have sufficient experience with 2D design software. And with slicing software too. As I said, with 3D editing software it's quite limited to the Revoscan app and Tinkercad. I can probably figure it out if I know what tool to use and what features to use approx. I did make some successful designs myself but this is around relatively simple shapes, not complex mesh objects (from photogrammetry). As I said, manipulating in slicing software is not the issue.

Comment: I tried to find the similar question, but the search capabilities or my lack in search qualities (probably this) did not com up with the question I remmenber from the top of my head...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associated with your other question, Meshmixer (and Fusion 360) will perform plane cuts. I feel that Meshmixer will accomplish easier the plane cut you seek, as one simply imports the model, selects the model by clicking on it, then from the tool bar on the left, selects Edit/Plane Cut. Manipulating the plane which appears with respect to translation and rotation is done with gizmos within the main window. Note the dialog box which should be set to re-mesh in order to properly close the cut.

One of the gizmos will allow you to select which side of the plane remains after the cut. If you make an error (in most programs), Control-Z will allow you to reverse the last few actions to try again.

Tinkercad can be used by creating a cube larger than the object, turning it into a "hole" and placing it to cut in the desired manner. Tinkercad will also glitch with too many triangles/facets, which leaves Meshmixer a better option in my opinion.

Please note that for both questions, you'll find helpful videos with tutorial approaches, to make your objectives that much easier. Too many to link in a practical manner.